# android send mms

Tags: android, mms

I found the mms sending example in following link

http://androidbridge.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-send-mms-programmatically-in.html

Here I came to notice that the subject field has been mention as

```
private void SetMessage(MMMessage mm) {
        mm.setVersion(IMMConstants.MMS_VERSION_10);
        mm.setMessageType(IMMConstants.MESSAGE_TYPE_M_SEND_REQ);
        mm.setTransactionId("0000000066");
        mm.setDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        mm.setFrom("+919560008648/TYPE=PLMN"); // doesnt work, i wish this
                                                // worked as it should be
        mm.addToAddress("+919990048184/TYPE=PLMN");
        mm.setDeliveryReport(true);
        mm.setReadReply(false);
        mm.setSenderVisibility(IMMConstants.SENDER_VISIBILITY_SHOW);
        **mm.setSubject("This is mms subject");**
        mm.setMessageClass(IMMConstants.MESSAGE_CLASS_PERSONAL);
        mm.setPriority(IMMConstants.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        mm.setContentType(IMMConstants.CT_APPLICATION_MULTIPART_MIXED);
}
```

but there is no way to send message along with the picture and sometime I found that MMS are sending in the form of link. If you have done this before then your help will be really appreciable.

Comment: If a MMS is sent with a link, then it's probably the phone company that are sending you this link, because your phone isn't set up to receive MMS.

Comment: yes you are right.. do you have any idea regarding sending message along with picture..